# How do I make my if statement ask the user to try again if the input is a negative number or a letter?

Tags: c, if-statement

How do I make my if statement ask the user to try again if the input is a negative number or a letter?

```
struct foodstuff {
    float amount;
};

void add(struct foodstuff *tmpAdd) {
    printf("Write amount: ");
    scanf("%f", &tmpAdd->amount);

    while (tmpAdd->amount != 0) {

        if (tmpAdd->amount < -1 || isalpha(tmpAdd->amount)) {
            printf("Type in a valid number!\n");
            printf("Write amount: ");
            getchar();
            scanf("%f", &tmpAdd->amount);
            getchar();
    }
    else {
        scanf("%f", &tmpAdd->amount);
        getchar();
    }
   }
 };
```

Comment: Read the line of user input with `fgets()` and then parse it.

Comment: Why use `tmpAdd->amount < -1` for " if the input is a negative number "?  `tmpAdd->amount < 0` makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can rephrase your code to use a `do` loop instead:

```
do {
    printf("Enter a positive number with no characters:\n");
    int result = scanf("%f", &tmpAdd->amount);
while (tmpAdd->amount <= 0 || result != 1);
```

Note that I have removed the call to `isalpha()`, which acts only a single character at a time.  Instead, I propose just checking that the entered number is a valid float and that it is greater than zero.  If `scanf` does not succeed to read in a valid float, then its return value would be not be 1 and the loop would repeat.  And the same is the case for entering a valid float which is a negative number.

Comment: I have to be able to enter a char

Comment: There is a still a problem with that, because how do you handle the case where a user enters two characters?  `isalpha()` would not cover this case.

Comment: Well, my teacher expects me to make it possible for the user to enter both a negative number and a letter.

Comment: You can enter whatever you wish using my solution.  But only a positive number will be accepted.  Strings and negative numbers will cause the loop to iterate again.

Comment: `tmpAdd->amount < -1` does not quite realize "checking ... it is greater than zero".

Comment: @Adrian You _have_ to be able to enter a `char`? I thought you wanted to consider a `char` as invalid input.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

As [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) said, you could first read the input with `fgets()` and then parse it.

Like

```
char buff[100], *ptr;
float f;
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin)!=NULL)
{
    buff[strlen(buff)-1]='\0';
    f=strtof(buff, &ptr);
    if(errno==ERANGE)
    {
        printf("\nPossible overflow.");
        errno=0;
        continue;
    }
    if(f<0 || *ptr!='\0')
    {
        printf("Type in a valid number!\n");
        continue;
    }
    tmpAdd->amount=f;
    printf("\n%f", f);
}
```

Here, `fgets()` is used to read the input on each iteration. `fgets()` will return `NULL` upon error.

The

```
buff[strlen(buff)-1]='\0';
```

is done because `fgets()` will read in the trailing `\n` into `buff` as well. We modify that `\n` to be the `\0` character denoting the end of string with `buff[strlen(buff)-1]='\0';`.

[`strtof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) is used to extract the value from `buff`. 
It is in `stdlib.h`.

In case `buff` has something other than numbers, the number part would be converted and returned by `strtof()` and the `ptr` pointer would be made to point to the first non-numeric part of `buff`.

So if the first character in the string pointed to by `ptr` is the `\0` character, there were no non-numeric parts in `buff`.

If the input value was too large or too small to be accommodated in a `float`, `errno` would be set to `ERANGE`. You need to include `errno.h` for that.

If overflow (or underflow) occurred, we set `errno` to `0` and continue.

And `(tmpAdd->amount<-1)` would be false even if `tmpAdd->amount` were `-1` and `-1` is negative. You need `(tmpAdd->amount<0)` instead.

Also, your loop would exit only when `tmpAdd->amount` becomes `0`. You could simply do

```
tmpAdd->amount=0;
```

if that would do.

Otherwise, you can add a

```
if(f==0)
{
    break;
}
```

at the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to my code, it looks like this now:

```
printf("Write amount: ");
scanf("%f", &(tmpAdd + index)->amount);
getchar();
do {

    if (tmpAdd->amount <= -1 || isalpha(tmpAdd->amount != 0)) {
        printf("Type in a valid number!\n");
        printf("Write amount: ");
        scanf("%f", &(tmpAdd + index)->amount);
        getchar();
    }
    else if (isdigit(tmpAdd->amount >= 0)) {
        scanf("%f", &(tmpAdd + index)->amount);
        //getchar();
    }
} while (tmpAdd->amount <= -1 || isalpha(tmpAdd->amount != 0));
};
```

Main looks like this:

```
int main (void) {

int input, noFood = 0;
int flag = 1;

printf("Welcome to the shopping list manager. \n\n");

struct foodstuff food1;

while (flag == 1) {

    printf("1 - add food\n");
    printf("2 - print shopping list\n");
    printf("3 - end\n\n");
    printf("What do you want to do? ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    clear();

    switch (input) {
    case 1: add(&food1, noFood); noFood++; break;
    case 2: print(&food1, noFood); break;
    case 3: printf("\nExiting program\n"); flag = 0; break;
    default: printf("Please enter a valid choice\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

And the output like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbvhM.png)

The only problem remaining is that when I want to add another item (add food) for the second time and I type a letter or a negative number, it doesn't run through the if statements.